# Relative URL filtering

Tags: url-rewriting

I am using the code below as part of the Relative URL plugin. It works well, except it is making external calls relative and I only want calls to my local site to be relative.
Is there a simple way to execute this code only on a certain URL string?

In other words only run this if the link contains "http://example.com" or "https://example.com"

[Here](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2012/06/relative-urls.html) is the code source:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rw_relative_urls' );
function rw_relative_urls() {
    // Don't do anything if:
    // - In feed
    // - In sitemap by WordPress SEO plugin
    if ( is_feed() || get_query_var( 'sitemap' ) )
        return;
    $filters = array(
        'post_link',
        'post_type_link',
        'page_link',
        'attachment_link',
        'get_shortlink',
        'post_type_archive_link',
        'get_pagenum_link',
        'get_comments_pagenum_link',
        'term_link',
        'search_link',
        'day_link',
        'month_link',
        'year_link'
    );
    foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {
        add_filter( $filter, 'wp_make_link_relative' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Urm, add a str_match for your site's URL and return without adding filters if the URL doesn't match?

Comment: trying not to be an idiot but could you show me that code snippet would work with the current  conditional if ( is_feed() || get_query_var( 'sitemap' ) )
        return;

Comment: @ajmartin - Trying to help, but I think I need a use-case that is causing you an issue. The plugin changes links that are generated in code to "Post" posts, custom typed posts, Pages, Attachments, Shortlinks, Archive Links, Pagenum links, comment links, Term links, Search links, and Day, Month and Year links. All of those would be internal, none of them external. So I'm not seeing where this plugin is causing you trouble. More info?

Comment: Use case would be "filter all links that contain domaina.com to be relative links to the root". So you could build site on domaina.com but then move it to domainb.com and no links break.  All external links would not be filtered. You could add a file type filter so you could limit to images, css and js. Basically this plugin uses the built in WP function add_filter( $filter, 'wp_make_link_relative' );

Comment: so all I really want to do is filter all links that partially match a given url string and filter those through the wp_make_link_relative

Comment: @ajmartin Thanks, but that's not was I was looking for. All the filters in the plugin filter URLs that by their very nature are root relative so I can't understand how to recommend a solution. Maybe if you can update your question and add a screenshot showing where links appear on your site that are incorrectly being changed, it would help.

Comment: The issue occurs when one of my plugins calls google fonts and google maps and then this filter makes those "non-local" links relative. Since I dont host google fonts or google map apis on my local machine those links become 404s

Comment: @ajmartin Okay, that's what I needed.

Comment: @ajmartin Can you tell me what plugins you are using to include the Google fonts and Google Maps APIs so I can test my answer?

Comment: Visual Composer Ultimate Add-on  Google Font and Google Map Modules  - Requires WP Bakery -  Because these are paid plugins it could be a hassle

Comment: @ajmartin: Yeah, it's going to be tough to figure this out without access to that code.

Comment: i am happy to test it if you want to email me code

Comment: @ajmartin I emailed you some code. Check it out and let me know if it works so I can post here as an answer.